# Smoluchowski diffusion equation for 2D diffusion

Tags: probability, differential-equations, diffusion

I am trying to solve the Smoluchowski diffusion equation, for 50 particles in the x/y plane.

I have derived the equations
$$
X(t+\delta t) = X(t) +\sqrt{2D\delta t}\phi_x \\
Y(t+\delta t) = Y(t) +\sqrt{2D\delta t}\phi_y \\
$$
following the logic of the mean square displacement, with a random walk, where D = diffusion coefficient, $\phi$ is a normally distributed random number, with zero mean and unit variance for each spatial dimension.

Help is very much appreciated, I would also be open to references also.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @pp.ch.te Im trying to solve the Smoluchowski diffusion equations for 50 particles in the x-y plane to simulate them

Comment: That was clear, but that is not really a question.. What is your exact doubt?

Comment: @pp.ch.te Im struggling with the calculations, I am trying to solve it numerically and I cant seem to be able to do it

Comment: Which calculations exactly? Try adding these details to your question